# Track all rewards paid to validator including it's delegators

Tags: staking, rewards, vote-account

I'm trying to find the average amount of staking rewards paid to a validator across an epoch. I am aware of the method [getInflationReward](https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getinflationreward), and I'm able to pass that method a validators vote account but I'm not sure if this amount returned includes that of delegators or not? How could I find the total staking rewards paid to a validator during a previous epoch?